# Kotlin & Databinding Int value null check issue

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-databinding

#### This is the weirdest problem I faced ever.

So again kotlin & data binding made me stuck. I start my question with the code.

**Model class**

```
data class ModelBottomItem(
        @StringRes val name: Int,
        @DrawableRes val image: Int,
        val gender: Int = 0,
        val enabled: Boolean = true,
        val disabledIconColor: Int = 0)
    : BaseModel()
```

**Layout code**

```
<variable
    name="item"
    type="myModel"/>


<TextView
    android:text="@{item.gender == 0 ? @string/male : @string/female}"
    ...
    />
```

**Debug trace list**

```
0 = {ModelBottomItem@6406} "ModelBottomItem(name=2131755043, image=2131230862, gender=0, enabled=true, disabledIconColor=0)"
```

> ```
> 08-10 12:57:12.388 24902-24902/acr.browser.barebones E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: acr.browser.barebones, PID: 24902
>     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
> ```
>
> blah, blah !!

#### If i change `item.gender == null`

#### Then the code is not able to build. It fails with below error.

> ```
> error: incomparable types: int and <null>
>                 itemGenderJavaLangObjectNull = (itemGender) == (null);
> ```

### Understand problem in two lines.

- When I check **`item.gender == null`** shows error `incomparable types: int and <null>`.
- And when I check for **`item.gender == 0`**, then code will crash saying **`int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference`** in case of 0 at run time. Even you can see debug trace, my model item is 0, it is not `**null**`. Even I have setted default value to gender, that is **`val gender: Int = 0`**. **Then how can it be null or 0?**

Comment: Does the stacktrace/error gives you the line number/property name? Can it be about other field (not gender)?

Comment: Yes I have checked it perfectly. It gives me line number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case use **toIntOrNull()** like this

```
 item.gender.toString().toIntOrNull()
```

Example

```
    val numb=""
    val numb2="7"
    val print1=numb.toIntOrNull()
    println(print1) //out put is null
    val print2=numb2.toIntOrNull()
    println(print2) // output is 7
```

your data model use nullable Int?

```
 gender: Int? = 0 as parameter
```

like this

```
 data class ModelBottomItem(
    @StringRes val name: Int,
    @DrawableRes val image: Int,
    val gender: Int?= 0,
    val enabled: Boolean = true,
    val disabledIconColor: Int = 0)
: BaseModel()
```

Comment: Did you try this? `****/ data binding error ****msg:cannot find method toIntOrNull() in class int`

Comment: use item.gender.toString().toIntOrNull()

Comment: ****/ data binding error ****msg:cannot find method toString() in class int

Comment: Already posted related code. You can try with creating a sample code with this.

Comment: If I take java model, there will be no problem, all problem is with kotlin data class.

Comment: which line you faced cannot find method toString() in class int  ??

Comment: Dude, obvious I got this error after adding toString(). So line number is same of that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177796/discussion-between-sasikumar-and-khemraj).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you havent properly called yourActivityBinding.setItem(your_item) in your Activity.

Try adding a break point in your activity to confirm you are not binding a null item to the layout

Comment: I have added my debug trace, which I got from debugging. By the way it is adapter not an activity.

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
android:someBinding="@{(Integer) null}"
```